# get subdomain cookies PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I have a domain for example `mukul.com` and a subdomain `nonprod.mukul.com`. Now there are some cookies set up for both domains separately.

```
<?php
echo json_encode($_COOKIE);
?>
```

The above code lists only the cookies of the domain i.e. `mukul.com`. I am looking for a way to list out the cookies of the subdomain also

Comment: Write this in subdomain's code.

Comment: need to get access from domain only @nice_dev.

Comment: You can't get cookies of one domain from the other via PHP code since cookies are stored on  client's browser. Accessing one site's cookies from other via javascript will lead to cross site scripting which is prohibited by default by all browsers.